# Add constant number to query() result in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I've a `QUERY()` function that results into this automatically generated table:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| S | 2 |
| F | 5 |
| G | 1 |

I'd like to add a constant value to each cell in column B like (let's say 3):

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| S | 5 |
| F | 8 |
| G | 4 |

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

We'll assume that your existing query is:

- `=query(A1:B4,"select A, B")`

Replace this with:

- `=query(A2:B4, "select A, B+3 label B+3 'B',A 'A'")`

Two things to note:

- **Range** - the header row is removed from the data range.
- **Labels** - the column labels are assigned manually.

FWIW, even if you included row#1 in the Data Range AND used a value of "0" for headers, a new header 'sum(3())' would appear above column B. So it is easier to exclude the header row altogether, and to manually assign labels for both Columns.

---

**Sample**

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In your `query()` formula, insert `+ 3` after the reference to column `B`.

See the [query language help page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Language_Syntax).